# How to get the all the strings from a list of different tuples with text and number in python

Tags: python, string, nlp

I have been having a great challenge in getting a list of text from the list of tuples below, which are the keywords I get from nltk library

```
[('supreme court justice ruth bader ginsburg may', 14.0),
 ('justice ruth bader ginsburg rightly holds', 12.0),
 ('vintage ruth— ‘ straight ahead', 10.0),
 ('fellow supreme court colleagues penned', 10.0),
 ('could make things better', 8.0),
 ('neighbor sanford greenberg says', 8.0),
 ('live. ” ginsburg ’', 8.0),]
```

This is the expected output i want to get

```
['supreme court justice ruth bader ginsburg may',
 'justice ruth bader ginsburg rightly holds',
 'vintage ruth— ‘ straight ahead',
 'fellow supreme court colleagues penned',
 'could make things better',
 'neighbor sanford greenberg says', 
 'live. ” ginsburg ’']
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use indexing

```
a=[('supreme court justice ruth bader ginsburg may', 14.0),
 ('justice ruth bader ginsburg rightly holds', 12.0),
 ('vintage ruth— ‘ straight ahead', 10.0),
 ('fellow supreme court colleagues penned', 10.0),
 ('could make things better', 8.0),
 ('neighbor sanford greenberg says', 8.0),
 ('live. ” ginsburg ’', 8.0),]
a=[x[0] for x in a]
print(a)
```